# Does pthread_cond_signal function unlock the mutex the calling thread locked?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

When i call 'pthread_cond_signal' during my thread's function, does this call unlock the mutex i currently use? (Not the one the pthread_cond_wait is waiting for).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the mutex given to pthread_cond_(timed_)wait() is unlocked to give other threads the chance to change the condition. At the end of pthread_cond_wait, the mutex is locked again. **No other functions lock/unlock mutexes**.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't unlock any mutex at all. `pthread_cond_wait` *does* unlock its mutex, and when it exits the mutex is locked again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure from my reading that both answers are saying about the same thing just in slightly different ways.